# Entity Framework Core scaffold additional tables not context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

From Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

When trying to reverse engineer your models and dbcontext from an existing database, you can run a command like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver; Database=mydatabase; Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -Tables FirstTable, SecondTable
```

This will create me two models and a dbcontext based on my connection details.

If I want to come back later and add another few tables, is it possible to run the same command, or something similar with different parameters that **will not create the dbcontext again**, as I already have this from my initial scaffold.

Currently we are running the command over and over again and deleting the context each time, or manually building any new models based on the database tables. It seems counter productive.

In Entity Framework 6 and below we would just maintain the edmx diagram but obviously this is not included in EfCore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's logged as a request with the EF Core team, but has been pending for a good while now.

[Github link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831)

Comment: As of November 13th 2023 this is still open :(. 9 years after it opened.

Answer (score 1):

In EFCore, there really isn't support for database first design.   The scaffolding feature is only meant to be a one-time operation to build your code first models/contexts so that you don't have to hand code them in order to get started using EF.  Once run the first time, you should be moving to EF Migrations instead of scaffolding to deal with additions/updates/deletes to the schema.

Here is MS documentation for migrations:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: "The migrations feature in EF Core provides a way to incrementally update the database schema to keep it in sync with the application's data model" My application is not dictating the schema of the database, this isn't a code first project, its the other way round?

Comment: Guess that was my point....EF Core was not designed to support database first, which is what it sounds like you are after.  The scaffold utility was meant to take an existing database and create all the necessary code first models/contexts for you as a starting point.  It wasn't meant to provide database first support to EF Core....at least that has been my understanding.   As for your "application not dictating the schema" comment, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Your models/contexts definitions should be extracted into their own set of projects so you can maintain them separately.

Comment: The database I'm connecting a front end to existed 10 years ago, and I'm not allowed to change it, there are hundreds of tables. As I don't want to bring in 200 entities at the beginning of a project but later down the line I get new requirements which require additional tables to be added - this leaves me with the originally described predicament.

Answer (score 0):

You can just re-generate the files again, all the generated classes are partial, and you can implement any customizations in parrallel partial classes.

EF Core Power Tools allows you to just generate the POCO classes or just the DbContext.